# URL of localhost using IIS

Tags: iis, asp

So I have IIS installed at work and use the following URL to test my asp site:

http://localhost/mysite/index.asp

I'm on the road and need to work on it. I have all the site files, but I don't have an XP disc so I installed IIS express. All the files and folder locations and names are the same, but the URL (http://localhost/mysite/index.asp) no longer works. What do I do?

Comment: Do you think that `but the URL no longer works` is a problem description? I don't. It's more of a rant and it would require some telepathic skills from the person answering your question in order to know what exactly is happening. What exact steps did you do? What is the expected result. What is the actual result? How does it differ from the expected result? That's how you should ask a question and not just say that something doesn't work. Not to mention that server configuration and administration questions should go to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Check the name of the virtual directory in iis

Answer (score 1):

How exactly have you setup IIS Express? Is it running on a custom port.

Check your system tray when you have the site running and you'll usually get an icon for the instance of IIS Express which will indicate the port number the instance is using.

You'd then connect using something like:

http://localhost:portnumber/mysite/index.asp